# Django to use different settings.py file based on subdomains

Tags: python, django, subdomain

How can Django use different settings.py file based on subdomains.

Can these utilities ("django-admin", "python manage.py") still be used if there were different settings connecting to different databases.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

ok you have two dimensions you need to cover with your settings:

1. Domain (site)
2. Current Machine

Here is what I recommend:

`universal_settings.py` - all the settings you want to inherit everywhere (all machines, all domains)

`local_settings.py` - settings on a per machine basis (database settings, mail server, etc)

`site_1.py` - settings that are specific to a one of your domains
`site_2.py` - settings that are specific to a one of your domains
`site_n.py` - you get the idea

the bottom of universal_settings.py should include:

```
from local_settings import *
```

This will override anything in the universal settings as necessary.

similarly, each of the `site_1.py`, `site_2.py`, `site_n.py` settings files should begin with:

```
from universal_settings import *
```

Finally you need to set up an apache (or nginx, or whatever) instance for each domain and use the appropriate `site_n.py` as the settings file for that server

This is the method that works best for me :)